# Navigate in a image with titanium

Tags: android, image, imageview, titanium, titanium-mobile

i recover a png file from a webserveur and i include it into an ImageView define like this :

```
var suivi = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    top:"10%",
    width:"100%",
    height:"90%"
});
```

the problem is : the file is higher and wider than the ImageView, so it is reduce to ajust to the size of the imageview. What i want , is to keep it's size and navigate with finger into this image. Do you know how to do ? is my question enough clear or i shoud rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question is how to keep the original dimensions on the image and be able to pan it around with your finger. Titanium does not have this feature natively. However there is a work around using a ScrollView instead.

```
var suivi = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    top:"10%",
    width:"100%",
    height:"90%"
});
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:'auto', 
    contentHeight:'auto', 
    top:0, 
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true, 
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
    minZoomScale:0,
    maxZoomScale:10, 
    zoomScale:0 
});
scrollView.add(suivi);
```

And add the scrollView to you window.

Answer (score 1):

try this one as auto is deprecated now a days and also instead of using % you can use Ti.UI.SIZE

```
var imgView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE
});
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:Ti.UI.SIZE, 
    contentHeight:Ti.UI.SIZE, 
    top:0,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true, 
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true
});
scrollView.add(imgView);
```